# Visual Studio Winforms App Cannot See Reference on Build/Rebuild

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

This should be a simple one... but it confounds me.  I am trying to test a third-party assembly using a very simple winforms app.  I add a reference to it in the project.  I then add an Imports (this is VB.Net) statement.  I continue on to call a method in a static class within the assembly within Form1_Load.  All of this is almost too much information...

Before attempting to build the solution the imports statement is fine.  The call to the method is fine (and by fine I mean visual studio "sees them."  When I build the solution it throws the error "'[NAMESPACE]' is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

I have tried removing the assembly to a more public directory.  In the reference properties copy local is true.

Any ideas?  I am at my wits-end over this silly problem.

Comment: Is it possible that these classes or methods you're trying to call are Protected, Internal or Private?

Comment: I had the same issue a couple of times. Adding them to the project and then restarting VS helped sometimes. Maybe that helps for you as well.

Comment: None of this helps but thanks.  I should note that after trying to rebuild I can't even see it in the object browser!

Comment: Here is another weird thing.  When my colleague tries it in VS 2013 it works.  I should note the assembly is built in Framework 2.0.  (In case you are thinking it has something to do with a higher framework)  Also... my visual studio is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  By default my projects were targeting Framework 4 Client Profile"  If I switched to the regular Framework 4... it works fine :-)